# Order List not showing in Tailwind & nextjs

Tags: html, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to show a ordered list on the page. I have use `<ol>` tag but the list is not showing me the numbers. I am not getting what's the issue here even the `<ul>` is not working here.

See this screenshot:

[image]

I am not getting why the list is not being rendered as ordered list in next.js & tailwind even I am using `<ol>` tag.

here's my code:

```
<div>
  <span className="font-medium">
    What Is Included In This eBook?
  </span>
  <ol start={1}>
    <li>1st Item</li>
    <li>2nd Item</li>
    <li>3rd Item</li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a [style](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/list-style-type) to your list item.

```html
<ol className="list-decimal">
  <li>Now this is a story all about how, my life got flipped-turned upside down</li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ol>
```